# Magento 1.9.0.1 Can't get pass checkout step 3 shipping, process stops

Tags: onestepcheckout

Im currently on magento 1.9.0.1, In my store page www.misimpresiones.com, a lot of time the checkout process stops at step 3. It not display an error, but not allowed to continue the buying process, it is locked in the selection step shipping. In order to continue the buying process, we clean our cookies and cache, but sometimes it doesn't work, we still have the same problem.

Anyone? Any ideas?

.[image]

Comment: Check whether you can find any JS errors in the browser console.

Comment: there's no shipping method available for your order. check your setting /conditions for shipping  try to more shipping method active to find extact problem whether it's shipping or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You get the shipping method block with AJAX from URL
http://www.misimpresiones.com/checkout/onepage/shippingMethod/

.

Possible path(s) to template:
`app/design/frontend/shopper/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

`app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

.

And that template contains Javascript code that blocks/halts to debugger:

```
var shippingCodePrice = {'freeshipping_freeshipping':0,'flatrate_flatrate':100};

$$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping_method"]').each(function(el){
    Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){
        if (el.checked == true) {
//            var getShippingCode = el.getValue();
debugger;   // <---- THIS LINE, REMOVE IT
            var getShippingCode = el.value;

                                var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];
                if (!lastPrice) {
                    lastPrice = newPrice;
                    quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;
                }
                if (newPrice != lastPrice) {
                    quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);
                    lastPrice = newPrice;
                }
                            checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;
            return false;
        }
   });
});
```

Hope that helps!